# A place on Earth, a visual association puzzle

Tags: knowledge, visual

This is not a rebus or a connect wall.  Or steganography.
This is a visual association puzzle.

Each of these pictures remind me in some way the same place somewhere on this planet.
(And it is not Hollywood).

Your task is to identify that place and show the link it shares with each picture.

PS: Actually the associations are not all visual.  But most are.

[image]

(bonus)
[image]   [image]

### Followup

The place has been (almost) identified.

There still is some work finding the the explanation behind each picture:

Karate kid: found.
Orca: found.
Flying kid: not found.
Raptor: 1/2 found.
Vador: not found.
Pen: found.
Alien xenomorph: not found.
Mechagodzilla: found.
Falling whale: not found.
Mars attacks: not found.
Pumpkins: not found.
Cup nooles: 1/3 found.
Moai: not found.

### Obligatory credits for the pictures.

These are not useful to solve the puzzle.

Darth Vader from [www.theverge.com](http://www.theverge.com)
https://www.theverge.com/2016/12/21/14040916/darth-vader-rogue-one-final-lightsaber-scene-star-wars

Killer whale from [www.wallmonkeys.com](http://www.wallmonkeys.com)
https://www.wallmonkeys.com/products/killer-whale-jumping-out-wall-mural-dsp-24000

Pumpkins from organicbio on [www.ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com)
https://www.ebay.com/itm/6-SEEDS-HEIRLOOM-HANGING-PUMPKINS-ORGANIC-SQUASH-UK-EU-Disease-Resistant-/143412424411

Pen from [www.penaddict.com](http://www.penaddict.com)
https://www.penaddict.com/blog/2018/11/28/stilform-kosmos-ballpoint-pen-review

Live raptor warning from [www.travelpulse.com](http://www.travelpulse.com)
https://www.travelpulse.com/news/entertainment/jurassic-world-stars-spoof-the-emotional-support-animal-debate.html

Falling whale and petunia from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy

Father and son from A Woman's View ~ Lenore Buth
https://awomansview.typepad.com/a_womans_view/2017/06/what-good-are-dads-in-a-childs-life-.html

Mechagodzilla:  from Wikipedia

Xenomorph:  https://www.hollywood-collectibles.com/HCG-Exclusive-Aliens-Facehugger.html

Mars attacks:  https://wallpaperaccess.com/mars-attack

Comment: rot13(vf vg fvtavsvpnag gung abg nyy bs gur perqvgf zngpu hc jvgu cvpgherf?)

Comment: rot6(hi).  I hate rot13

Comment: rot26(sorry, i didn't know)

Comment: rot13( :-) ) no problem.  Btw I removed the orphan credits.  They were just alternatives to the pictures shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure on the exact location and I have not yet found all connections but I think this has something to do with

> NASA and SpaceX, So I think it's either Kennedy Space Center or SpaceX Starbase, where the Starship rocket is supposed to launch from.

First row:

> - Chopsticks: SpaceX's [Robot Chopsticks](https://futurism.com/the-byte/spacex-installs-robot-chopsticks)
>  - Orca that looks like a rocket.
>  - That kid is flying like the rocket will be. Also it is being caught in a way that might remind you of mechazilla operations

Second row

> - SpaceX's [Raptor Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor) is certainly going to be live there and you better stand clear.
>  - Not quite sure about Vader but Star Wars *is* set in space...
>  - The pen could either reference the [NASA pen story](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/) or be a visual reference to how the [SpaceX Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) and its two stages look.

Third row

> - Aliens would certainly come to mind when talking about space exploration.
>  - [Mechazilla](https://futurism.com/the-byte/spacex-starship-booster-chopsticks) is the name for the machine assembling Starship.

Fourth row:

> - The whale and flowerpot are a reference to the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, unfortunately for the whale, "The knack [of flying] lies in learning how to throw yourself at the ground and miss." A quote from the series which explains spaceflight.
>  - That's Mars Attacks (how did I miss this??) and colonizing Mars is one of SpaceX's goals
>  - I have no idea what the pumpkins are supposed to mean.

Bonus

> - Chopsticks again.
>  - No idea about the Moai either.

Comment: You are right for about half of the explanations.  And about half of the proposed locations.  The explanations would deserve some improvements.  But you did the hardest.  It seems that the exact reason for each picture is far less obvious than I expected.  Let's see if others can be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping someone would take up the challenge and match the remaining images but it seems the interest has faded.

So here is a complete solution.

> As already discovered, the location is Starbase, Texas.
>  More precisely it is the the launch site and its orbital launch tower.
>
>  And here you find the visual analogue of the pictures above.
>
>   [image]

Comment: It seems too hard to associate these images with the images in question, I feel. Unless these images are quite famous.

Comment: Actually I was worried it would be too easy.  But you are right.  I guess the problem is that the natural association would be the other way round, i.e. from solution image to enigma image.  Or you need to have followed closely the latest evolution of ... well ... that place.